# Timeout expired error in ASP.NET but not on SQL Server Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, timeout

In my ASP.NET application, I am getting the following error:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

But I can successfully connect to the database server using 'SQL Server Mangement Studio' and I can also correctly PING the host where SQL Server is hosted.

What can be wrong here.

Comment: Have you profiled the query that causes this issue to determine if it can be optimised. Just because you can connect/ping, does not mean all is well in the SQL world.

Comment: You always can increase timeout of you connection. But you need to shou some code

Comment: UPDATE: connection.Open() is successful so the problem seems on the adapter.Fill() side. Increasing connection timeout will not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string in web.config.  The connection string you are using via SQL Management Studio is different to the one in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase timeout in web.config too which is better or say best approach.

Also whenever you get this type of error and everything is good in confirable, then first debug the code,

1. if the issue code side, then you manage simply by changing logic.
2. If it is sqlserver side, then get the parameter value and sp or query. Run in to SSMS which gives you better idea.

Answer (score -1):

Increasing Command timeout to 120 fixed my problem for me.

adapter.SelectCommandCommandTimeout=120;